# Does forEach not run if there is only one element in an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I created the following code:

```
                topicService.topics.forEach(function (row: ITopicRow) {
                    if (row.topicId == $stateParams.topicId) {
                        row.current = true;
                        topicService.topic = angular.copy(row);
                        topicService.topicBase = angular.copy(row);
                    } else {
                        row.current = false;
                    }
                })
```

When the function code is called and $stateParams.topicId is set to a number it searches through the rows and sets current to true on that particular row.

However I have a problem in that it does not work if there is only one topic. In this case the forEach does not even run. Below is the line that shows the length of 1. I can also see when I hover over topics that is says it is an array[].

var x = topicService.topics.length; x = 1 <<<<<<

Note that when I put this right before the forEach and when I put a debug point on the first line of the forEach it does not go there.

Is there some way that I can fix this using forEach or would I need to have code just for the case where there is only one topic?

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't run? Have you tried stepping through it in the developers console?

Comment: Yes I tried that and it does not go into the forEach area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common that some API functions return array if multiple items are present and return an item instead of `"array with one item"` if only one item is present. So, `topicService.topics` may not even be containing an array.

That's most probably, why `forEach` is failing in your case. so add a check:

```
if( topicService.topics.constructor === Array) {
    // do foreach
}
```

Comment: The forEach is not so much failing.  It's not running. I have checked the contents of topics before it gets to forEach and it shows as an array[] I also checked and it has a length of 1.  However in debug it never goes into the forEach.

Answer (score 0):

For each will work if there is just one, you must have a mistake somwhere else in your code try printing out the number of elements in topicService.topics just before you run the forEach I would guess something has change it to 0